# pandas daily moving windows eucledian distance

Tags: python, pandas, euclidean-distance

I have a pandas dataframe which has two columns (time-series) that I need to compare. These time-series are hourly based, but I need to compare them every day (24h => compare, then I move the window 24 hours ahead).

The method I want to use is the Eucledian distance. I had this idea:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def myrolling_apply(df):
    a = df['predicted'].values
    b = df['actual'].values
    dst = distance.euclidean(a,b)
    return(dst)

rr['dst'] = pd.rolling_apply(rr, 24, myrolling_apply)
```

but the passed df, is a ndarray. How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give 5 rows on data you are using!

Comment: @user3378649 It's like http://pastie.org/9705423

Comment: Check this, u might find it helpful https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/936

Comment: @user3378649 :( damn, it's helpful and sad. Nevertheless I can't "rolling_apply", because I don't have a dataframe in the function...